# Parent height jumps when transitioning child's height (CSS)

Tags: html, css

I got a structure similar to this:

```
<div>
  <div>
    <div>
...
```

I am trying to transition the inner div's height from 0 to 100%. The transition works, but the parents height does not change smoothly but jumps abruptly before/after the transition (see gif).

[image: screencast]

All three divs have flex display. The inner div's transition is:

```
.expandable {
 transition: max-height 2s linear;
 max-height: 0;
 height: auto;
}

.expandable.expanded {
 max-height: 100%;
}
```

Codepen with a minimum reproducible example: https://codepen.io/raquelhortab/pen/GRxNzGb

Comment: please share your code with sandbox url

Answer (score 0):

While expanding to `100%` works for the element's own transition, the parents do not recalculate the height during the transition. However, using an exact value does the trick.

```
.expandable.expanded {
 max-height: 240px;
}
```

It is quite an inconvenient solution when you don't know the exact height it will have.